# My "module event" is not loading arguments

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make an event that loads arguments in-script, but it is returning args as nil.
Can someone help?

Code:

```lua
local Bindable = {_functions={}}

Bindable.__index = Bindable

function Bindable:Connect(args)
    table.insert(Bindable._functions,args)
end

function Bindable:connect(args) return Bindable:Connect(args) end

function Bindable:Fire(args)
    for i,v in pairs(Bindable._functions) do
        v(args)
    end
end

sickdankbeatz.OnSync = Bindable
```

Comment: how is this code used? I don't see you return args anywhere

Comment: this code does exactly what it is implemented for. so either you expect something different or you're using it the wrong way

Comment: Possibly some issue with using `.` instead of `:` at the call site. `self` isn't used anywhere in the code above ...